# Python: Make a list unique and replace the duplices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I want to find the unique list with preserverd order of a list of integers, where the duplicates are replaced with zeros. It is all in the context to find the nearest points from a set of  multidimensional points to another.

**Example**

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(100,4)
b = np.random.rand(200,4)
tree=scipy.spatial.cKDTree(a)
indexesOf_neighbors= tree.query(b, 1)[1]
_, idx = np.unique(indexesOf_neighbors, return_index=True)
print(indexesOf_neighbors)
print(indexesOf_neighbors[np.sort(idx)])
```

So the first appearences of a number should be preserverd. All folowing duplicates should be replaced with np.infs like:

[38 66 79 10 35 83 99 89 68 65 20 np.inf 46 np.inf 24 51 13  0 17 87 90 54 45 63
 69 56 np.inf 32 62 49 99 67 82 np.inf 64 np.inf np.inf np.inf ... ]

Another option would be to find all indices of the duplicates (but not their first appeareance)

Comment: 1. Zero or np.inf? You can only pick one. 2. Is that code necessary? Why not just show the list before processing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making an array with np.inf, and then replace the unique positions?

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(100,4)
b = np.random.rand(200,4)
tree=spatial.cKDTree(a)
indexesOf_neighbors= tree.query(b, 1)[1]
u, idx = np.unique(indexesOf_neighbors, return_index=True)
print(indexesOf_neighbors)

u_indexesOf_neighbors = np.empty(indexesOf_neighbors.shape, dtype=np.float64)
u_indexesOf_neighbors.fill(np.inf)
u_indexesOf_neighbors[idx] = u
print(u_indexesOf_neighbors)
```

result

```
[82 61  4  5 32 48 62 80 50 96 84 49 37 58 17 80 52  1 33 76 50 24 22 31
  3 77 71  3 30 43 89 67 74 18 39 72 96 16 29 29 11 59 83 12 55  3 34 87
 74 93 21 96 83 89 21 61  3 81 39 93  8 80 64 47 83 27 46 34 72 64 34 42
 72 82 74 70  0 23 56 14 69 88  2 87 26 56 89 53  3 33 94 43 43  8 86  2
 76 10 95 71 99 76 82 87 92 97 92 25 61 48 94 15 55 86 35 87 83 66 39 79
 77 57 62  1 43 74 27 34 16 83 29 34 31  2 90 51  1  2 33 17 30 96  2 82
 22 44  0 88  7 33 36 55 95 94 64 54 86 36 34 24 48  1  7 68 77 30 70 24
 28 73 43 16 20 56 55 94 63 71  5 38 86 46 23 66 48  1 72  7  8 88 56  1
 80 85 84  7 97  2 55 35]
[82. 61.  4.  5. 32. 48. 62. 80. 50. 96. 84. 49. 37. 58. 17. inf 52.  1.
 33. 76. inf 24. 22. 31.  3. 77. 71. inf 30. 43. 89. 67. 74. 18. 39. 72.
 inf 16. 29. inf 11. 59. 83. 12. 55. inf 34. 87. inf 93. 21. inf inf inf
 inf inf inf 81. inf inf  8. inf 64. 47. inf 27. 46. inf inf inf inf 42.
 inf inf inf 70.  0. 23. 56. 14. 69. 88.  2. inf 26. inf inf 53. inf inf
 94. inf inf inf 86. inf inf 10. 95. inf 99. inf inf inf 92. 97. inf 25.
 inf inf inf 15. inf inf 35. inf inf 66. inf 79. inf 57. inf inf inf inf
 inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf 90. 51. inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf
 inf 44. inf inf  7. inf 36. inf inf inf inf 54. inf inf inf inf inf inf
 inf 68. inf inf inf inf 28. 73. inf inf 20. inf inf inf 63. inf inf 38.
 inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf 85. inf inf inf inf
 inf inf]
```

I picked float64 dtype. But you can choose any.

Answer (score 0):

make an independent copy of the list in case you need the original later on:

```
unique_list = indexesOf_neighbors.copy()
####keep track of unique items
unique_set = []

for idx, i in enumerate(unique_list):
    if i not in unique_set:
        unique_set.append(i) #add first non-repeating element to set
    else:
        unique_list[idx] = 0 #replace duplicates with zero
```